# Moment of inertia of wheel-and-dart system

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

The problem I'm currently struggling with is:

A wheel of mass M (assumed to be concentrated at its rim) and radius R is mounted horizontally so it may turn without friction on a vertical axle. (i.e. ignore gravity). A dart of mass $m_0$ is thrown with velocity $v_0$ in the plane of the wheel, and sticks into the right side of the wheel.

The angle made by the path of the dart and the radial line outwards at the point of contact is $\theta$.

Find the angular velocity $\omega$ after the dart strikes.

The first step, I believe is to break up the initial momentum into radial and tangential components. The tangential component of the momentum is the only one that will change the angular velocity.

From drawing a diagram, I found that $\sin(\theta)=\frac{p_t}{m_0v_0}$, where $p_t$ represents the component of the initial rightward momentum that is directed tangential to the circle at point of impact.

I then equated this with rotational momentum, namely:

$I \omega = m_0v_0\sin(\theta)$

And here's were I hit a bit of a road-bump. You see, I know that the rotational inertia of the wheel itself is $MR^2$, and likewise that the moment of inertia of the dart is $mR^2$, but I am not sure what to do to combine the two. Do I just add them? Is the moment of inertia of the resulting system just $(m+M)R^2$?

It doesn't say we can neglect the mass of the dart once it combines with the wheel.

Comment: Yes, the IM of the system after the collision is $(M+m_0)R^2$ because both object rotate about the same axis.

Comment: @Gert Ah I see; this is just parallel axis theorem. I didn't recognize it at first but now it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!